# Error with provisioning profile during app installation

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, mobileprovision

I have following error while trying to install application (ipa) on device:

```
entitlement 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'XXXXXXXXXX'
```

This error start to appear after I generated new provisioning profile with new certificates. If it can be helpful, below are different part of old provisioning profile and the new one.

Old:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>FSKCIFJNWO.com.XXXXX.YYYY</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>FSKCIFJNWO.*</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>FSKCIFJNWO.*</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>FSKCIFJNWO.*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
...
```

New:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>FSKCIFJNWO.*</string>
    </array>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>FSKCIFJNWO.com.XXXXX.YYYY</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>FSKCIFJNWO.*</string>

    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <string>*</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
    <array>
        <string>Development</string>
        <string>Production</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>FSKCIFJNWO</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>

</dict>
...
```

Maybe I did something wrong while generating provisioning profile. 
Question: Do you know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a production PP, and as far as I can see no Enterprise Account.
You will not be able to install an IPA build with this PP on a device without having the registered devices listed.

Comment: I took only a part of my PP and didn't include device's ids in my message. However my PP has them. It was a first thing that I checked.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you do not have all the services selected for your app id on Apple's developer site.  Check out your settings and make sure you have all of the necessary options selected.  Then re-generate your provisioning profile:

[image]

Also, make sure your app bundle id matches the ID on Apple's site.